# Retrieve path when assetExport is completed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm exporting a video in a function and then when it is done the path is added to a `variable`. In another method i would like to call this method and then save it when it is completed. i've tried using background queue, but it keep saying that the variable is nil? how can i achieve this?

**CreateVideo**

```
func createVideo() {

    //  create new file to receive data
    let docsDir: AnyObject = documentsPath
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)
    _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(movieDestinationUrl)

    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    assetExport!.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition

    assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        default:
            print("Movie complete")


            // save to photoalbum
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in


              self.movieUrl = movieFilePath
            })


        }

    })

}
```

**Save VIdeo**

```
func saveVideo() {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
            self.createVideo()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.movieUrl!,  self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

            })
        })


}
```

Comment: It looks like that, the movieFilepath variable gets deallocated before we assigning the value of it inside the block.

Comment: yes i agree, what is the solution for this?

Comment: Check answer please, and let me know whether its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that, the `movieFilepath` variable gets deallocated before we assigning the value of it inside the block. You should use `dispatch_queue` in `dispatch_get_mainQueue()`.

```
func createVideo() {

    //  create new file to receive data
    let docsDir: AnyObject = documentsPath
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)
    _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(movieDestinationUrl)

    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    assetExport!.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition

    assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        default:
            print("Movie complete")

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                self.movieUrl = movieFilePath
     })

        }
    })
}
```

This is because, we have no idea about when NSOperationQueue is going to execute the operation.

Comment: inside the ` NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()` or instead of?

Comment: `movieUrl` is still nil when i `print(self.movieUrl)`

Comment: Doubt. Why are you assigning the value inside the block, while you can do it in outside ?? I mean outside `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: will it not then be executed before the export is completed?

Comment: Also just wanted to confirm that, are you sure that `movieFilePath` is not nile outside `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: yes i've done a little debugging and can see that `saveVideo()` is executed before the export is completed